# Do imports carry over when importing a script

Tags: python

From my understanding, when you are importing a script to run, from another script, the imports will carry over to the new script. I.E. I import pandas in the script below, and now pandas is imported to the new script, so I no longer need to write "import pandas as pd" in the new script.

I know there is this answer: [Do a python module's imports need to be carried over when importing that module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570601/do-a-python-modules-imports-need-to-be-carried-over-when-importing-that-module) but that appears to be discussing custom imports (e.g. from app-helper). I'm discussing more general imports like os, pandas, numpy, time, sys, etc.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import time
import sys

if input('Will you be using the free or bound state peaks? (Type in "Free" or "Bound")\n').lower() != 'free':
    import slow_exchange_bound
    sys.exit()

#rest of the script
```

Based on the above script though, if I don't have all the import lines in my slow_exchange_bound script, then it doesn't run properly (i.e. in slow_exchange_bound, I have to reinput import os, import pandas, etc.)

Comment: There is no difference between what you call "custom import" and "general import". Every module is imported only once, but it is not available in local namespace of all modules (what you call "script" is a wrong name as well) automatically. So, you should actually write "import pandas" wherever you want to use pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need `import pandas as pd`, etc in `slow_exchange_bound` so that the name `pd` is available in the global namespace of `slow_exchange_bound`. The "carryover" comes from the fact that the module is only *evaluated* once; subsequent imports find the module in `sys.modules` already and simply add a reference to the module to the relevant namespace.